# End Session / PHPSESSID on Chrome close

Tags: php, session, opencart

Im using opencart 2 and i made box where you can ask for phone call if you have any question about product, each time you send phone call request its record product ID and session_id

```
        $data_fast['product_id'] = $this->request->post['product_id'];
        $data_fast['session_id'] = $this->session->getId();
```

than in View template i compare your session and product to see if you have been send request about this product to display or hide button "ask for phone call" (kind of spam protection) when you close the browser your session end that is ok BUT on Chrome your session still same after browser close if Option: "Continue where you left off" is on, so you will never see again this button for this product . Is anything i can do even if this Chrome option is ON to run with new session every time when browser is open as other browsers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can lower the session time for the server. 
put these values in your php.ini

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 86400
session.cookie_lifetime = 86400
session.cache_expire = 86400
```

adjust the times based on your need.

Comment: is it gonna lower and admin session time as well ?

Comment: Yes. it is going to shorten the admin session as well.

Comment: do you have any different suggestion for other kind of spam protection than this?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can store the customer_id/phone_number and product_id in a table. So that you can check whether this customer or phone number already requested or not. Do you really need a session for this?

Comment: the session i use is to compare in view if he already send request or not ( to display or hide button "ask for phonecall")  other way he can just refresh page and send it again and again .... so until session is same he wont be able to send request again for same products, when he close the browser and come back again next days he will have new session and will be able to send request again if he want for same product

Comment: Then what about storing the phone number and product_id in a table. And check whether this request has been already made or not?

Comment: they are guest even if i storing their phones and product_id on page refresh i cant compare this information because they dont have profile

Comment: What are the data user submits on clicking the button "ask for phonecall"?

Comment: product_id , phone, session_id . When you refresh page if product_id and session_id match you cant request phone call again . If you close the browser session end (that is fine but problem is Chrome if Option: "Continue where you left off" is on keep same session forever) . if you come back next days and want again phone call request for same product its fine you have new session so you can do it BUT if Option: "Continue where you left off" is on session is same so you cant do

Comment: You are storing the phone. Then why you can't store the phone and product_id and Check this request has been already made or not on button click.

Also "Continue From Where You Left" is also available in firefox.

Comment: If i record phone and product id when they open X product button "ask for phone call" will be visible , i dont like button to be visible if he had made request for this product at this day or at lees until browser was closed

Comment: Then Why Not Use Cookies For Tracking User?

Comment: that may be better idea than sessions

Comment: Sure It Will Be.